# Keep a double at a max of 1.0

Tags: java, math, modulus

Ok this should be a rather simple problem but I just can't get this right.  I have a cumulative sum that's returning a double.  These represent percents and it should never be 0.0..  so I figured use d % 1 to keep things under 1.  Works fine for 2.13 which becomes 0.13, or 2.98 becomes 0.98, however 3.0 becomes 0.0 not 1.0 (100%)..

I'm obviously doing something fundamentally wrong here?  or perhaps I just cheat and say if 0 then 1?

Thanks

Comment: What does 2.0 give you?  I don't completely understand what you are doing.  As a general rule, use BigDecimal when doing math in Java.

Comment: 2 % 1 = 0.. it's a running list of decimals but every time it hits a whole number I want it to result in 1 so 1, 2, 3,..,n = 1, 1, 1, 1. Or 1.1, 2.1,...,n.1 = 0.1, 0.1 etc

Comment: do you want `0 % 1` => `1` ?

Comment: Your question is lacking a clear specification: why do you accept a function that is not monotonous ? (like `f(1.98) > f(2.13)`). IMO this is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **when cumulative (percentage) sum hits 1.0 (100%) boundary**

   - why to set it to `sum=sum%1` ?
   - if the meaning is a percentage of some operation then should not it be still `1.0` ?
   - so while summing I would do something like this instead:

     ```
     for (...)
      {
      // some stuff of yours
      sum+=...;
      if (sum>1.0) sum=1.0;
      }
     ```
2. **if you still need the modulus 1 then you can exploit floor**

   - but that operation does not give any sense to me (other than pulsing progress bar)
   - unless the sum is used for something else then I think

     ```
     for (...)
      {
      // some stuff of yours
      sum+=...;             
      if (sum>1.0) sum-=floor(sum);
      }
     ```
   - if your sum can be negative then handle negative values separately with `ceil`
   - if the `1.0` is also not wanted then ignore the `if` and sub the floor(sum) always
3. **if you know the target sum**

   - if sum is representing progress state
   - and you know the last value (entire sum)
   - then the `percentage=sum/whole_sum);`

Answer (score 2):

% is the Modulus operator

From wikipedia:

"In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus)"

In other words 3 modulo 1 = 0 because the remainder after dividing 3 by 1 is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The modulus is behaving as expected - there is no remainder when dividing 3.0 by 1.0.

If you want to handle the special case of no remainder:

```
d %= 1.0
d = d == 0.0 ? 1.0 : d;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `x/(x+a)` or `1-exp(-ax)` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust and very nice if  target sum is known just approximately :) didn't think of that (+1)